# Parse json in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

I have json like:

```
{
    "member": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "lastname": "string",
          "email": "string",
          "address": {
             "city": "string",
             "country": "string"
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

I parse with the fromGson(google)

```
Gson().fromJson(jsonString,Member::class.java)
```

I already have a class to map this json on each field

```
data class Member(
        var name: String,
        var lastname: String,
        var email: String,
        var address: HashMap<String, String>
        
)
```

but I have problem to map address, I don't know why
it's only work when json like

```
"address": 
{
  "city": "string"
}
```

it look like I need parse map on json object whos in json object too

array of hashmap didn't work also

Comment: What is the issue? Does it throws an exception? If so can you add the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need a wrapper class on the top of member class, try this:

```kotlin
private val jsonString =
        "{\"member\": [{ \"name\": \"string\",\"lastname\": \"string\",\"email\": \"string\",\"address\": { \"city\": \"string\",\"country\": \"string\" } }]}"

    data class Member(
        var name: String,
        var lastname: String,
        var email: String,
        var address: HashMap<String, String>
    )

    class Response(val member: List<Member>)

    fun parse() {
        val response = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Response::class.java)
        for (member in response.member){
            // do something
        }
    }
```